# Joining string that is broken up on multiple elements in the list

Tags: python, replace, substring

Given a list of strings like this (input):

`["some test", "{", "some", "_subst", "ring}", "some", "other text"]`

Need to combine all the elements in to one for the given substring (input).

For example:

`substring = "{some_substring}"`

The output list of strings will be

`["some text", "{some_substring}", "some other text" ]`

Here are few more possible lists of strings:

```
input_list = ['some test', '{', 'sub', 'string}', 'som other text']
input_list2 = ['some test', '{sub', 'string}', 'som other text']
input_list3 = ['some test', '{', 'sub', 'string}', 'som other text']
input_list4 = ['some test', '{', 'sub', 'string', '}', 'som other text']
input_list5 = ['some test {', 'sub', 'string', '}', 'som other text']
input_list6 = ['some test {', 'sub', 'string', '} som other text']
```

`substring` can be any text and it does not need to be wrapped in to round braces. If `substring` appears multiple times in the input string than it should be replaced as well.

***Note*:** *Elements of the string that do not contain part of the input string should be the same instances.
So creating a new list from joned string will not work for this problem.*

*In the system where I solve this strings carry additional information like style. So removing or replacing them will remove style as well*

Signature of expected function to better understand problem.

```
def join_variable(input_list, substring):
    # implementation
    return output_list
```

My take on it:

```py
def join_substring(example, variable):
    i = 0
    result = []
    while i <= len(example):
        if example[i] in variable:
            if example[i].startswith('{'):
                result.append(example[i])
            else:
                result[-1] = result[-1] + example[i]
        else:
            result.append(example[i])
        i += 1

    return result
```

But you see here I have hardcoded a `{` which is not necessary per my understanding.

Comment: So how do you are planning to identify `variable`, is "some test" always equal? Moreover what have you tried?

Comment: *"round brackets"*: you mean braces? Why not give a few more examples without braces? How will you identify the variable then?

Comment: You can join it and use regex to extract the info: `re.match(r"(.*)({[^}]+})(.*)", ''.join(example)).groups()`

Comment: @DaniMesejo No, it's can be any text.

Comment: @trincot I've provided signature below so it should be clearer now. variable will be provided as an arbitrary string.

Comment: what if `substring = 'me_variab'` (i.e. we try to match any substring of `''.join(lst)`)?

Comment: @PierreD Yes, that's right.

Comment: What if variable appears several times?

Comment: @DaniMesejo It shoudl be joined as well. I'll add this detail to the body of the question

Comment: That didn't answer my question... if "some substring" is not wrapped in braces, and could be any text, then how.will.you.know.what.to.extract?

Comment: @trincot we provide a variable as input parameter in to joining function in additon to input list

Comment: any comment on whether my answer is fitting the bill?

Comment: Added a few comments on why we can't use joining and splitting here, and essentially any for matching regex.

Comment: why not reformulating your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Provide just enough test cases to _fully_ describe the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you allow to match anywhere, you can join the list and check for substring in that:

```py
def join_variable(input_list, variable):
    s = ''.join(input_list)
    if variable in s:
        parts = s.split(variable, 1)
        return [parts[0], variable, parts[1]]
```

Example:

```py
test_cases = [
    ["some test", "{", "some", "_var", "iable}", "some", "other text"],
    ['some test', '{', 'var', 'iable}', 'som other text'],
    ['some test', '{var', 'iable}', 'som other text'],
    ['some test', '{', 'var', 'iable}', 'som other text'],
    ['some test', '{', 'var', 'iable', '}', 'som other text'],
    ['some test {', 'var', 'iable', '}', 'som other text'],
    ['some test {', 'var', 'iable', '} som other text'],
]

[join_variable(input_list, '{some_variable}') for input_list in test_cases]
# out:
[['some test', '{some_variable}', 'someother text'],
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None]

[join_variable(input_list, 'variable') for input_list in test_cases]
# out:
[['some test{some_', 'variable', '}someother text'],
 ['some test{', 'variable', '}som other text'],
 ['some test{', 'variable', '}som other text'],
 ['some test{', 'variable', '}som other text'],
 ['some test{', 'variable', '}som other text'],
 ['some test {', 'variable', '}som other text'],
 ['some test {', 'variable', '} som other text']]
```

Comment: This works for this particular case. But one detail I forget to mention, is that i'm not allow to touch list elements that do not contain par of the variable. So for this problem on iteration over the variables will work most likely.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but in any case, please provide more test cases (counterexamples) along with the expected output.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. I should better design requirements. I's confusing. I'm gong to update question soon.

Comment: I've added details to the body of the question. About why we can't use join and split here. I'm sorry for not putting this detail originally, I did not even think of this solution.